# Como depurar un bloque try/catch (desarrollo android-xamarin)

Tags: c#, xamarin, xdebug

estoy desarrollando en c# una aplicacion para android, y tengo un bloque try/catch que debo revisar, paso a paso, pero cuando ejecuto, no se me detiene en el breakpoint. Hay alguna manera?

```
private async void onSaveAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
// recuperar imagen 
Stream x;
byte[] buffer;
Stream reqStream;
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create("ftp://elftp/archivo.png");
try
{
x = await signature.GetImageStreamAsync(SignatureImageFormat.Png);
// this is actually memory-stream so convertible to it
var mstream = (MemoryStream)x;
//Unfortunately above mstream is not valid until you take it as byte array
mstream = new MemoryStream(mstream.ToArray());
//long longitud = mstream.Length;
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("usuario", "password");
request.UsePassive = true;
request.UseBinary = true;
request.KeepAlive = true;
buffer = BitConverter.GetBytes(mstream.Length);
mstream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
mstream.Close();
reqStream = request.GetRequestStream();
reqStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
reqStream.Flush();
reqStream.Close();
}
catch (DirectoryNotFoundException dirEx)
{
// Let the user know that the directory did not exist.
Console.WriteLine("Directory not found: " + dirEx.Message);
} 
}
```

El problema de este código, es que la imagen que es graba en el ftp no es la imagen del signaturepad, sino algo como un icono pequeño, que no contiene nada. Hay un problema en la recuperación de la imagen como tal, y el momento de prepararla para subirla al ftp.

Solucionado!!! Era un tema de tipo de variable.. tenia que usar el typo Byte.

Gracias

Comment: Y si pones el breakpoint antes?

Comment: Pon el código que lo veamos, por favor

Answer (score 2):

En el codigo que has puesto veo dos cosas.
La primera el Console.WriteLine solo funciona en proyectos tipo consola, en un proyecto visual (wpf, xamarin, etc...) tienes que poner Debug.WriteLine

La segunda, tienes un bloque de codigo relativamente grande y la única excepcion que capturas es la del tipo DirectoryNotFoundException es decir, que solo va a entrar en el catch si dentro de todo ese bloque da un fallo de que no encuentra un directorio. Si quieres ver cualquier otro error puedes hacerlo tal que asi:

```
catch (DirectoryNotFoundException dirEx)
{
    // Let the user know that the directory did not exist.
    Debug.WriteLine("Directory not found: " + dirEx.Message);
} 
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Generic error: " + ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: Perfecto, gracias. Englobando todo un poco, ya tengo el signaturepad, que me graba en un ftp como archivo png, sin el fondo gris (parámetros de signaturepad), y para pedir el nombre del archivo, le he puesto un control 'textbox'. Al pulsar el guardar, y una vez 'guardado' el archivo, me sale un aviso (alert), que me indica que el archivo se ha guardado bien. Tengo mejoras por hacer, pero ya esta funcionando. Me gustaría en vez de tener el control text box, que me pidiera el nombre una vez pulso el botón de guardar, con un cuadro de dialogo. Poco a poco se va aprendiendo. Gracias